# Formatação de imagens no CSS figure.class

Tags: css, html5

(Resolvido) Parece que o arquivo .css estava corrompido, criei um novo e reescrevi o mesmo código nele, após isso o código passou a funcionar normalmente.

Estou com um problema para colocar os atributos em uma imagem no CSS, eu salvo o arquivo e não modifica em nada minha imagem, sendo que os outros atributos (body e p) estão funcionando normalmente.
OBS: A imagem esta aparecendo, entretanto o atributo (borda) não funciona.

Segue o código do CSS e HTML respectivamente.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  background-color: gray;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 50px;
}


/*formatação imagens*/

figure.foto-legenda {
  border: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="glass-quadro-homem-mulher.jpg">
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Google Glass</h3>
    <p>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo></p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: A sua imagem está aparecendo na tela pelo menos, ou nem a imagem aparece? Vc quer que a borda vermelha fique só na imagem é isso?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito a sua dúvida... Tente adicionar os atributos da imagem, no css, sob **.foto-legenda > img {**. Ficaria algo como _.foto-legenda > img {
  width:100%;
}_

Comment: hugocsl, a imagem esta aparecendo, porém a borda não esta. 
Erika, não entendi direito... Coloquei esse código e não mudou nada...:
figure.foto-legenda {
 width:100%;
 border:8px solid red;  
}

Comment: Considerando o *edit* na pergunta, é quase certo de que vc está passando por um problema de *cache* do navegador! Sempre que alterar um arquivo invocado pela página, utilize Shift + F5 (Chrome) ou então desabilite o cache enquanto o DevTool (Ctrl + Shift + i)(Chrome) estiver aberto (Ctrl + Shift + i > F1 > Preferences > Disable cache)(Chrome). Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica LipESprY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questão de hierarquia: a ***.foto-legenda*** está acima de ***img***

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  background-color: gray;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 50px;
}
/*formatação imagens*/
.foto-legenda > img {
  border: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="glass-quadro-homem-mulher.jpg">
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Google Glass</h3>
    <p>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo></p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Esse código é o que você procura?

Comment: Sim, esse código, porém a borda continua não aparecendo ao redor da imagem, pode ser questão de tamanho da imagem ou borda?

Eu gostaria de enviar o código todo, mas eu ainda não entendi como formatar direito nos comentários.

Comment: @Texspray Teria como você mandar algum link, ou imagem, de como você gostaria do resultado? Algum site, ou página, que tem exatamente o que você procura para poder mostrar...

Comment: aqui esta o link do vídeo pelo qual eu estava estudando [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3mlsAk4G2k&t=440s)
O código do HTML aparece aos 6:38, já o do CSS aos 7:20.
Fiz exatamente como no vídeo e a borda não aparece aqui.

Comment: Não sei o que está acontecendo com os seus testes... Seguindo as instruções do vídeo, você realmente consegue o resultado. Para demonstrar, peguei o seu código - postado originalmente lá em cima - e acrescentei exatamente o que o carinha do vídeo disse. E o resultado foi _exatamente_ o mostrado por ele. Segue este exemplo no [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEamXq) e no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erikamac/z961t4wk/2/). Fale se algo não estiver de acordo.

Comment: Erika, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo, o resultado que eu esperava era esse mesmo que você me mandou. Eu acabei resolvendo o problema, pelo o que parece o arquivo .css estava corrompido, voltou a funcionar depois que criei um novo e reescrevi o código nele.

Comment: Ótimo saber que tudo saiu bem! Continue aprendendo e boa sorte!